# codeigniter htaccess rewrites the url to the BASEPATH../

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

i have a website that i made with codeigniter it works relativly fine on the local machine but when i uploaded it to the server it gives me a 500 error, and the error is gone when i remove the htaccess, and in the local machine the error appears in a different way some times i couldn't find what causing this but some urls get rewritten like this:
the original url => http://domain.com/controller/method
the rewritten url => http://domain.com/absolute/path/to/controller/method
here's my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

any help, thanx in advance.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite loaded on your server? What does your error logs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with my `.htaccess` code........

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: sorry i'm only at 12 reputation can't upvote until i reach 15.